# Integrate Koin in AAR

Tags: android, sdk, aar, koin, android-koin

I have an AAR project, and i'm trying to integrate Koin (my first Koin project).
I'm following Koin instruction for context isolation (https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/context-isolation/). and i will be glad to get some help.

I need to register the koin context this way:

```
MyKoinContext.koinApp = KoinApp
```

I don't understand when should i call this line and what is the KoinApp (should be `koinApplication()`?)

The second part that i'm not sure is that i should configure KoinComponent:

```
abstract class CustomKoinComponent : KoinComponent {
    // Override default Koin instance, initially target on GlobalContext to yours
    override fun getKoin(): Koin = MyKoinContext.koinApp?.koin
}
```

but `getKoin()` should return Koin and not Koin? how sholud i changed it.